# Porting Java code for creating Excel sheet to Android?

Tags: java, android, porting, xls

I am newbie in Android so anyone please help me to solve my problem. I am trying to create a **.xls** sheet in android and save it on the SD card, but it produces an error. My code is working well in Java. The main problem is that I am unable to convert the complete code in Android.

Any HELP will really be appreciated. Thanks a lot.

Comment: What error are you getting? Does the code compile? Does it start to run but then fails? Does it never even start to run?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most likely the library that you are using for writing the Excel file is not Android compatible.
Read this [post](http://www.wiseandroid.com/post/2010/07/16/Porting-existing-Java-code-to-Android.aspx), especially the part about ""Things to watch out for".